# How to access each row in Triangular numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, multidimensional-array

Given triangular numbers are as follows:

```
4
5  3
9  2  21
1  46 12  8
.... upto n rows.
```

Need to get the highest number from each row and sum it up.

I'm not able to figure out where and how to put all the n rows (like 2D array) and how to select each row from it.

Comment: why not just read the array item from size minus one like array[size-1] ?

Comment: Why have you named them `Triangular numbers`? Is there anything special about them. And yes, you need an `array of array` to store such structure. Better even, a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: I have named it Triangular numbers, since the number of elements in each row increases such that for nth row there are n elements.

Comment: @NikhilAraballi did you try to write any code ? Please share your code with us.

Comment: Do you just want the sum of maximum, or you also want to print that representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a `List<List<Integer>>` instead of `array`, then your job would be quite easy by using [`Collections.max`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

```
// The below syntax is called `double braces initialization`.
List<List<Integer>> triangularNumber = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>() {
    {
        // Add inner lists to the outer list.
        add(Arrays.asList(4)); 
        add(Arrays.asList(5, 3));
        add(Arrays.asList(9, 2, 21));
        add(Arrays.asList(1, 46, 12, 8));
    }
};

int sum = 0;
for (List<Integer> innerList: triangularNumber) {
    sum += Collections.max(innerList);
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] matrix = { { 4 }, { 5, 3 }, { 9, 2, 21 }, { 1, 46, 12, 8 } };
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        int maxInRow = matrix[i][0];
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(matrix[i][j]);

            if (maxInRow < matrix[i][j]) {
                maxInRow = matrix[i][j];
            }
        }
        sum = sum + maxInRow;

    }
    System.out.println(sum);

}
```

Try this:

Answer (score 0):

Why not work with a map? If you need to know each row's index you can do it like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> numbers = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>();
```

as for finding the maximum one can use:

```
Collections.max(...)
```

[JDK doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29)

This should do the trick.